# How to queue something in a Cypress test

Tags: chai, cypress, spy

I have the following test for [a custom Cypress command of mine](https://github.com/Svish/cypress-helper-history):

```js
it('can navigate to a url', () => {
  const history = createHistory();
  cy.window().then(win => ((win as any).__chh__history__ = history));

  cy.spy(history, 'push');
  history.listen((location, action) => {
    expect(action).to.equal('PUSH');
    expect(location.pathname).to.equal(PATH);
    expect(location.state).to.equal('foobar');
  });

  cy.navigate(PATH, 'foobar');

  cy.wait(0).then(() => {
    expect(history.push).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

The command works fine, but if I remove the `cy.wait(0)`, only doing the `expect`, then the test fails.

I assume it's because the `cy.navigate` command (added via `Cypress.Commands.add`) is queued, like other Cypress commands, meaning the `expect` actually runs before any of the Cypress commands have even started?

If so, that's fine and as expected of course, but is there a way in Cypress tests to queue things, without using `cy.wait(0)`?

For example when I'm checking elements, I can use `cy.get(something).should($el => expect(...))`, but in this case, there's nothing to "should on"... I could of course `cy.get('body')` or whatever, but I don't really want to get *anything* in this case.

Comment: I think the trick is to do anything that involves a `cy.window().then` is to put it in the `beforEach()` block, so that it completes before your proper test starts

Comment: In this case, that `cy.navigate` call is specifically what I'm trying to test. So doing it _before_ the test wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy.html#Method) show use of a naked `expect()` after the spy has been established,

```js
cy.spy(util, 'addListeners')  
App.start()  
expect(util.addListeners).to.be.called
```

but I think this is misleading, since `expect()` runs immediately but intervening Cypress commands may have inherent delays or reties, and can't be guaranteed to complete before the expect is executed.

Two other ways to test this are:

**Ensure the expect is only run after your custom command**

```js
cy.navigate(PATH, 'foobar').then(() => {
  expect(history.push).to.have.been.called;
})
```

**Put the expectation into the Cypress command queue**

```js
cy.navigate(PATH, 'foobar');
cy.wrap(history).its('push').should('have.been.called')
```